# Why do I need round() function with time()?

Tags: python

Here is an example of code I often see:

```
import time
def gettime():
    return int(round(time.time()*1000))
```

In this case, what is the reason of using `round()` in this code? `time.time()` always returns 1-2 digits after the decimal, so `round()` function seems useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is *not* useless, `time.time()` in my system returns something like:

```
1430407063.751232
```

multiplying by 1000 returns:

```
1430407063751.232
```

`round` rounds this to `1430407063751.0`, but if it was  `1430407063751.532`, it'll round it to `1430407063752.0`.

[`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html#time.time):

> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.

Comment: Epoch as mentioned above refers to January 1, 1970. It is also called Unix time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 3):

One reason could be, that some of the system don't return milliseconds, so you have same behaviour on all systems. As an example:

```
>>> time.time()
1430407091.766831
>>> round(time.time())
1430407097.0
```

On some systems Python is running on 1430407097.0 would be the "normal" return value.

Answer (score 2):

The `int` function don't round the the number the same way the `round` is:

```
int(0.7) == 0
```

But:

```
round(0.7) == 1.0
```